# Sorting a ADO.NET Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview, datatable

I have a datatable in C#.

```
DataTable dtClientMedications = new DataTable();
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Id");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("MedId");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("BrandName");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("GenericName");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Type");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Dosage");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("Status");
dtClientMedications.Columns.Add("SortOrder");
```

I want to sort in by the column SortOrder & assign it to a gridview. I used this:

```
gdvMainList.DataSource = dtClientMedications.DefaultView.Sort[7];//dtClientMedications;
gdvMainList.DataBind();
```

But it gives index out of bound exception.

Comment: It will depend on your datatable column length. How many columns does your datatable contains?

Comment: There are 8 columns as I have given the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing what the `Sort` property is in fact.

It is the expression that you want to sort. A `string` value, not index of columns. Your code tries to read the 6th `char` in an assumed existing sort `string`, no more!

Use

```
dtClientMedications.DefaultView.Sort = "SortOrder";
```

Before data binding.

```
gdvMainList.DataSource = dtClientMedications.DefaultView; // You may not need to mention view
gdvMainList.DataBind();
```

.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.sort.aspx

Comment: okay, can I assign a DataView to Gridview as a datasource? like I do with the datatable.

Comment: Yes. I think so. I haven't done this in a while but I think assigning either will be similar, since it is a "default" view anyway. See the updated code in the answer.

Comment: Working perfect. Thanx Mohamed Meligy

Answer (score 1):

`Sort` is string property.

Use,

```
dtClientMedications.DefaultView.Sort="ID"
```

Comment: Doesn't the datasource have to support the Sort method?

Comment: @asma: in answer to your first comment, yes, use `...Sort="SortOrder"`

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the columns in the table itself:

```
dtClientMedications.Columns["SortOrder"].SetOrdinal(0);
```

Comment: I want to sort all columns in fact the whole datatable by SortOrder.